# TeamCity 6.x and Mercurial via SSH (on Windows)

Tags: ssh, mercurial, teamcity, tortoisehg

I'm trying to reconfigure our TeamCity build server (running on WIN 2008) and switch from SVN to Mercurial repository. 
I use the following link as [Configuring Mercurial (Hg) with TeamCity over SSH at RepositoryHosting](http://www.hmemcpy.com/blog/2010/09/configuring-mercurial-hg-with-teamcity-over-ssh-at-repositoryhosting/).
I spent several days and still can't get it work. 
I can reach the Mercurial repository from TeamCity (via Test Connect) and I can pull code from Mercurial via TrotoiseHG, but the build fails every time because TeamCity cannot pull source code from the server.

Does anybody had the same issue?

Comment: Is there anything in teamcity-vcs.log related to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Agent-Side checkout instead of the default?  Otherwise, TeamCity tries to "intelligently" detect changes and distribute them to build nodes. Failure can occur whenever something happens in the VCS that TeamCity doesn't understand how to replicate, such as using subrepos.